# mysql if statement else returns the next one

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following table in mysql:

```
     +         +          +
 id  | state   | phone    | files
+------------------------------------+
 1   | on      |  123123  | file1
 2   | on      |  124423  | file2
 3   | off     |  123455  | file1
 4   | off     |  128455  | file3
 5   | on      |  323132  | file3
 6   | off     |  124454  | file4
     |         |          |
     |         |          |
     |         |          |
     +         +          +
```

I want to select the who has file1, and based on that I check the state,  if there is a off state I select the phone number if there isn't any off state I select the first one who has the file1 in table.

In next time the sql query executes, does the same process and if there weren't no off state it returns the next one phone number who hast the file1 but not the previous person. how can I do this?

Comment: sometimes an example is more understandable than one thousand words

Comment: I.e. add expected result as well. (Why the MS SQL Server tag?)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT t.id
     , t.state
     , t.phone
     , t.file
  FROM mytable t
 WHERE t.file = 'file1'
ORDER BY t.file, t.state, t.id
LIMIT 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Your statement should looks something like

```
select phone from mytable
where file = 'file1'
    and state = 'on'
    and id > :last_id /* you'll need to provide the previously popped id as a variable */
order by id asc
limit 1;
```

For a working example in PostgresSQL:

```
\set last_id 0
select phone from ( values
    ( 1, 'on', 123123, 'file1' ),
    ( 2, 'on', 124423, 'file2' ),
    ( 3, 'off', 123455, 'file1' ),
    ( 4, 'off', 128455, 'file3' ),
    ( 5, 'on', 323132, 'file3' ),
    ( 6, 'off', 124454, 'file4' )
) x ( id, state, phone, file)
where file = 'file1'
    and state = 'on'
    and id > :last_id
order by id asc
limit 1 ;
```